# Where can I find Mnesia source code?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I've seen in a lot of documents that Mnesia has been open sourced by Ericsson, but straightforward googling didn't help me to find the repository with the code...

Is Mnesia still open-source at all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's part of the Erlang/OTP source code, which you can get from [github](https://github.com/languages/Erlang). You can browse it [here](https://github.com/erlang/otp/tree/maint/lib/mnesia/src).

Comment: Look in the downloadable releases from www.erlang.org, it an application in the src directory.

Comment: Your link to mnesia sources is broken now. Change to [this one](https://github.com/erlang/otp/tree/maint/lib/mnesia/src).